# Low pas filter time constant for a square input

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, pcb-design, circuit-design, low-pass

I am trying to plan a low pass filter as in the picture:
[image]

I use it to create an ON/OFF lag (Is this the correct term?)
I have calculated the time constant τ of the system:

[image]

My question is:

- How do I calculate the time constant for the same circuit, but with a square (not sine) input?

Comment: The time constant refers to the system, not the signal.

Comment: The time constant, \$\small \tau\$, is defined by the circuit, not the signal(s). In this case, \$\small\tau=RC\$. Also 'delay' is the wrong word here; it should be 'lag'.

Comment: I would like to do that but there is no equation editor here In math forum for example I use $$ to insert an equation. Is there something similar here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the calculation seems a little problem

1. τ is a constant number which is only defined as τ=RC ,regardless of what input signals.
2. The phase lag @ f=fc is -45 degree calculate as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is this the calculation for the square wave? Also, what is A(f) and, The graphs are from a simulator (what simulator if I may)  Thanks again!

Comment: Matlab can do this simulation

Comment: And，if you don't have matlab ,there is also a website :

Answer (score 3):

> Why people always take 4.7kΩ and not, say 5kΩ ?

Well, because there are some standard values (called E-values) for resistors they are manufactured. The reason behind this is easy: this way you can create any resistance value with the right combination of these.

> How do I calculate the time constant for the same circuit, but with a square (not sine) input?

A square wave is a combination of infinite sinusoidals (see Fourier transformation) so you won't get an exact expression for any calculation regarding frequency, you can only calculate things for different sinusoidal components of the square wave

Comment: Can I get an estimation? If yes is it what is done in the answer of Lukeluck? Thanks!

Comment: Estimation of what? The time constant you were talking about in the question is the property of the circuit and is independent from the source

Comment: I thought so too but my adviser asked me to give a solution specifically for a square said what i gave was for sine only... I'm beginning to be tired of not understanding what people are taking about... anyways, thanks a lot for your effort and detailed calculation and graphs...

Answer (score 1):

And，if you don't have matlab ,there is also a website:
[Online simulator](https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=wt3nym)

[image: SCH]
[image: Phase-frequency Plot]